XLOOKUP with flexible column for return_array and not unique values in lookup_array



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M




1
Products

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M






2















3
Product A

Shop3

80
2%

120
22%






4
Product B

Shop1

320
17%

400
15%



Data from Column


5
Product B

Shop3

470
30%

750
8%

2024-S Selected

2024-M


6
Product B

Shop2

500
4%

70
4%

400

15%


7
Product C

Shop2

160
10%

245
10%

400

35%


8
Product D

Shop1

500
8%

130
4%

70

4%


9
Product D

Shop4

130
11%

130
4%

520

42%


10
Product E

Shop2

75
8%

650
15%

130

4%


11
Product E

Shop1

60
47%

90
7%

90

7%


12
Product E

Shop4

500
25%

400
35%

130

4%


13
Product E

Shop3

350
9%

140
13%

130

9%


14
Product F

Shop2

60
30%

130
9%

70

16%


15
Product G

Shop2

90
5%

370
12%






16
Product H

Shop1

390
27%

70
16%






17
Product H

Shop2

70
18%

520
42%








In Range M6:M14 I want to get the corresponding data based on the values in Range K6:14. 
However, I want to have the flexibility that the values in Range M6:M14 are selected based on the column header entered in Cell M5. 

In the table Column 2024-M is selected. 
If I change Cell M5 for example to Column Header Products the Range M6:M14 should look like this:
Product B
Product E
Product B
Product H
Product D
Product E
Product D
Product F
Product H


Summarized, I am looking for something like this:
Range M6:14 =XLOOKUP(K6:K14,$H$1:$H$17,Based on input in Cell $M$5,NA(),0)


Note: 

The lookup_array will always be the same. In this example Range $H$1:$H$17. 
Values in the lookup_array are not unique. In this example 130, 400 and 70. 
If a value in the lookup_array is not unique it will always appear with the exact same frequency in Range M6:M14 as you can see for 130, 400 and 70 in the example. 
The solution from this question does not work here because the results in Range M6:M14 should not only be corresponding to the values Column A. It can be any column in the table beased on the Column Header entered in Cell M5.


What formula do I need to make the outcome in Range M6:M14 work based on the selected Column Header in Cell M5?

Wouldn't you need to change the lookup array along with the lookup range? The logic of searching for the percentages that do not belong to that year's sales (Or isn't S sales) doesn't add up for me.

In that case this could work: =VLOOKUP(K6:K11,FILTER(E3:I17,LEFT(E1:I1,4)=LEFT(M5,4)),2,0)

Here is what you can do to achieve the desired output, using one single dynamic array formula:


=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, H3:H17,
     _RollingA, MAP(_A,LAMBDA(α,COUNTIF(α:K6,α))),
     _RollingB, MAP(_B,LAMBDA(α,COUNTIF(α:H3,α))),
     XLOOKUP(_A&"|"&_RollingA,_B&"|"&_RollingB,XLOOKUP(M5,A1:I1,A3:I17)))


Also, the last question, which is tagged with the present query both are different, even though the subject line stated about flexible column, but in context of the OP it was nowhere mentioned that the output column needs to be flexible, please try to be succinct and clear with your questions.

To explain a bit about the above solution, we are using MAP() function to create a cumulative/rolling/running counts for the respective arrays which have duplicates viz. Selected One and the Lookup array, in order to create a unique sequence or lookup value, to arrive at the desired output.

Or, Using by creating custom LAMBDA():
=LET(
     α, K6:K14,
     δ, H3:H17,
     ƒx, LAMBDA(ε,φ, MAP(ε, LAMBDA(Σ, COUNTIF(φ:Σ,Σ)))),
     XLOOKUP(α&"|"&ƒx(α,K6),δ&"|"&ƒx(δ,H3),
     XLOOKUP(M5,A1:I1,A3:I17,""),""))


Bit similar method applied here by me Display FILTER results in the same order as the values in the criteria range


I think one of the reasons you guys use Greek letters in LET is to make sure variable name doesn’t clash with cell references (A1, B2 etc). But how do you type Greek letters easily, do you have a special keyboard dedicated to Greek characters or something?

Excel Shortcuts. ALT+224 --> α , ALT+235 --> δ etc

I see. Still need to memorise those first.


Formula in M6:
=MAP(K6:K14,LAMBDA(x,@DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(E3:H17=x,F3:I17),F1:I1=M5),3),COUNTIF(K6:x,x)-1)))


Need to include col A to get 'Products', right? :)

I think you are right. I read past that requirement. Too late now to adjust. Thanks for the notification though @nkalvi.

I will just do it with helper columns, and use formulas step by step:
First in cell N5, input a number 0.
In cell N6, write below formula:
=XMATCH(K6,DROP($H$3:$H$17,O6,0),0,1).
In cell O6, write below formula:
=SUM(--($K$5:K5=K6)*($N$5:N5))
Drag down the formulas in both column N and column O, you will get this:

Here is what column O does:
e.g cell O7 = 2, meaning row 2 in H3:H17 has value = 400, so in order to find the "next" 400 in H3:H17, we need to drop the first two rows in H3:H17 before we do a XMATCH.
Cell N7 = 8; meaning the 8th row in H5:H17 has value = 400.
(we drop the first two rows, so lookup array is H5:H17 instead of H3:H17).
Finally, we get the final results in column P.
The formula in cell P6:
=INDEX(DROP($I$3:$I$17,O6,0),N6,1)
You can drag it down.
If you want to display values based on the header in M5, just change the formula to below: (replace I3:I17 with XLOOKUP($M$5,$A$1:$I$1,$A$3:$I$17))
=INDEX(DROP(XLOOKUP($M$5,$A$1:$I$1,$A$3:$I$17),O6,0),N6,1)


Similar to other methods, i.e. using running frequencies (with SUM):
=LAMBDA(h_, k_, data_range, col_headers, header_for_match,
    LET(
        i_index, XMATCH(header_for_match, col_headers),
        i_, INDEX(data_range, , i_index),
        freq, LAMBDA(arr,
            LET(
                indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),
                MAP(
                    indices,
                    LAMBDA(i,
                        SUM(IF(TAKE(arr, i) = INDEX(arr, i, ), 1, 0))
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        h_freq, h_ & " " & freq(h_),
        k_freq, k_ & " " & freq(k_),
        xlook, XLOOKUP(k_freq, h_freq, i_),
        formatted, IF(
            RIGHT(header_for_match, 2) = "-M",
            TEXT(xlook, "0%"),
            xlook
        ),
        formatted
    )
)(H3:H17, K6:K14, A3:I17, A1:I1, M5)


